# Rails 4 trying to submit form onchange of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, onchange

I am trying to have the below form submit changes and update my cart whenever the select option changes but I cannot seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<%= form_for(line_item, :html => {:id => "item-id"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :quantity, [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9], [10, 10]], selected: line_item.quantity, onchange: "$('#item-id').submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does the browser console say when you try it? Any errors?

Comment: There are no errors. I don't even think it's triggering.

Comment: Could you possibly post the actual generated HTML as well for the item list?

Comment: Can you also post the errors that from the rails server log?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but just an fyi, instead of:
`[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9], [10, 10]]`

You can simply do:
`options_for_select(1..10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a look at documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select we will see, that the select method accepts as options as html options, so as the second hash is not specified, the mentioned option will be ignored. But following will work:

```
<%= f.select :quantity, [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9], [10, 10]],  { selected: line_item.quantity }, { onchange: "$('#item-id').submit();" } %>
```